# Operator -> in malloc function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Watch here:

```
struct mystruct{
 int a;
 int b;
};

int main(void){
 struct mystruct* ptr;
 ptr = malloc( 10*sizeof( struct mystruct ) );
```

In this way I have allocated an array of struct.
If you try to print, for example ptr[4], you will notice a pointer.
When I have a pointer and I have access to a member, I have to use the -> operator right?
But if I do:

```
ptr[4]->a
```

It doesn't work! I must do

```
ptr[4].a
```

to make it work... why? I have a pointer!
ptr[4] = (ptr+4) right?

Also in normal arrays this happen:

```
struct mystruct array[10];
array[4].a
```

but array is a pointer!

Comment: "If you try to print, for example ptr[4], you will notice a pointer" - no, you won't (well, depending on how you try to print such a thing). ptr[4] is of type `struct mystruct`, it is not a pointer.

Comment: "ptr[4] = (ptr+4) right?". Wrong! `ptr[4]` is `*(ptr+4)`. Notice that `*`? `ptr[4]` is not a pointer.

Comment: You allocated an array of `struct mystruct` not an array of `struct mystruct *`... and `[ ]` offsets *and dereferences*, giving the struct in the array, not a pointer to it.

Comment: Also, an array isn't actually a pointer (though you can use indexing brackets with a pointer too).  The array here is the group of structs you allocated, not the pointer that tells you where they are.

Comment: "but array is a pointer" - **NO**!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array[4]` is *not* the same as `array + 4`. It's the same as `*(array + 4)`.

`array + 4` is certainly a pointer, but `array[4]` is the value pointed to by the pointer (which, of course, might also be a pointer if `array` were an array of some pointer type.)

Since `x->y` is essentially the same as `(*x).y`, you could rewrite `array[4].a` as `(array + 4)->a`, but you'd have a hard time getting that past most code reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

when you use square brackets on a pointer, it's similar to dereferencing the point. Therefore, it requests the p[].a syntax, and not the p[]->a

```
(p + 4)->a is essentially the same as p[4].a
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ptr` has type `struct mystruct *`, then `ptr[i]` has type `struct mystruct`; IOW, `ptr[i]` is not a pointer value.  Thus, you need to use the `.` component selection operator instead of `->`.